# traversing an ast having complex conditional expression to generate linq expression

Tags: c#, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, irony

I'm using Irony.net for generating a parse tree out of the source. Essentially I'm using ExpressionEvaluatorGrammer like grammer for binary expressions (arithmetic, relational and logical/conditional). I want to convert the resultant parse tree into Linq expression by traversing it. However, the tree does not seem to have a formation directly convertable to linq conditional expression. Hypothetical example of such an expression:

```
1 == 1 && 4 - 1 == 3
```

generates (pseudo xml tree for brevity):

```
<binary>
  <binary>
    <binary>
      <literal>1</literal>
      <op>==</op>
      <literal>1</literal>
    </binary>
    <op>&&</op>
    <binary>
      <literal>4</literal>
      <op>-</op>
      <literal>1</literal>
    </binary>
  </binary>
  <op>==</op>
  <literal>3</literal>
</binary>
```

In the tree above, the arithmetic expression (4 - 1) becomes the right expression to the && logical operation as the parent node closes after it. In the ideal world, it should have been a left expression of the nodes representing "== 3".

How do you traverse such a tree to generate a proper and operation? Or, is there a way to generate the tree in the form I desire?

Edit: here's the grammer (partial) definition. I have taken it from ExpressionEvaluatorGrammer that comes with Irony.interpreter.

```
RegisterOperators(15, "&", "&&", "|", "||");
RegisterOperators(20, "==", "<", "<=", ">", ">=", "!=");
RegisterOperators(30, "+", "-");
RegisterOperators(40, "*", "/");
Expr.Rule = Term
Term.Rule = number | ParExpr | stringLit | FunctionCall | identifier | MemberAccess | IndexedAccess;
ParExpr.Rule = "(" + Expr + ")";
BinExpr.Rule = Expr + BinOp + Expr;
BinOp.Rule = ToTerm("+") | "-" | "*" | "/" | "**" | "==" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">=" | "!=" | "&&" | "||" | "&" | "|";
```

Comment: I don't know Irony.Net but the xml it generates corresponds to ((1==1)&&(4*1))==3. Either it is the case that && and == has equal precedence while * has a higher precedence or it is a bug. You might try to add paranthesis before parsing, or use another tool. If the actual grammar is not much more complicated it should not be difficult to write a parser (that directly generates an expression) by hand.

Comment: What do your calls to `RegisterOperators` look like and how do you set up the associativity?

Comment: @sixlettervariables please see the grammer with precedence

Comment: It does appear that your precedence is correct, but that the grammar is not respecting that `==` should bind tighter than `&&`. Which version of Irony are you using? The [author recently fixed a precedence/associativity bug.](http://irony.codeplex.com/discussions/286380)

Comment: @Ali right now my needs are not complex (assentially I need a conditional expression parser) but in future the language may be extended with loops and so on. If it can be done with Irony, I would be able to extend it easily

Comment: @sixlettervariables I think latest. I have recently downloaded from codeplex.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Ok, it seems this has been fixed this week. I downloaded it couple of weeks back. will try it and give feedback. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming the operator precedence is correct*, you should walk the tree recursively using the Visitor Pattern, returning an `Expression` at each level:

```
XName xBinary = "binary";
XName xLiteral = "literal";
Expression Visit(XElement elt)
{
    if (elt.Name == xBinary)
    {
        return VisitBinary(elt);
    }
    else if (elt.Name == xLiteral)
    {
        return VisitLiteral(elt);
    } // ...

    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Now that you have the `Visit` structure, you simply write each specific visitor to use your main `Visit`:

```
Expression VisitLiteral(XElement elt)
{
    Debug.Assert(elt.Name == xLiteral);
    return Expression.Constant((int)elt);
}

Expression VisitBinary(XElement elt)
{
    Debug.Assert(elt.Name == xBinary);
    Debug.Assert(elt.Elements().Count() >= 3);

    var lhs = elt.Elements().ElementAt(0);
    var op = elt.Elements().ElementAt(1);
    var rhs = elt.Elements().ElementAt(2);

    switch((string)op)
    {
    case "+":
        // by chaining LHS and RHS to Visit we allow the tree to be constructed
        // properly as Visit performs the per-element dispatch
        return Expression.Add(Visit(lhs), Visit(rhs));
    case "&&":
        return Expression.AndAlso(Visit(lhs), Visit(rhs));
    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, the xml "tree" generated by Irony.Net is incorrect.

Comment: @Ali: just noticed that, sounds like a precedence problem instead. Once the precedence is fixed, the OP could use the Visitor Pattern.

Comment: Upgrade fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fix this by traversing the tree in a magical/special way. Your parser is incorrect! Probably, it is just misconfigured. You absolutely need to get the correct tree from it in order to process it further.

Probably you have wrong operator precedence rules in it. It looks like it, at least. Try adding parenthesis to see if it fixed up the tree.